# Using %-based width divs inside a container with px-based margin

Tags: html, css, responsive

Bit of a beginner's question here - I'm sure it's been asked many times over but not knowing how to phrase the question means I've found it hard to find answers.

I'm trying to create 3 "cards" in a div which are responsive. I would like the margin between the cards to stay at 20px.

[This is what I've come up with so far](https://jsfiddle.net/3gg8ngm2/1) - the contents of the card container should add up to 965, so I'm not sure what's causing it to break and spill out, unless I'm doing something else wrong.

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1280px;
}

.card-container {
    max-width: 965px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: block; 
    float: left;
}

.card {
    width: 33%;
    min-width: 295px;
}

.one {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #333;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.card + .card {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="one"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="one"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="map-card"></div> -->
</div>
```

Thanks for any help, or redirecting to a similar topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex` like this https://jsfiddle.net/3gg8ngm2/2/:

```css
.container {
 max-width: 1280px;
}

.card-container {
 max-width: 965px;
 padding: 0 20px;
 display: flex;  
}

.card {
 width: 33%;
 /* min-width: 295px; */
}

.one {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: #333;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

.card + .card {
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-container">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="one"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
    <div class="one"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
    <div class="one"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="map-card"></div> -->
 </div>
```

Or you can also use `display-inline-block` to your `.card` class.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution based on `display: flex`

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
}

.card-container {
    display: flex;
    background: yellow;
}

.card {
    width: calc(33% - 20px);
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.card:first-child {margin-left:20px}

.one {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="one">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="one">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="one">3</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
.card {
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
    min-width: 295px;
}
```

and will resolve your issue.